# Reloading a fragment Error [android.view.InflateException]

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

Hi i am creating a map in a fragment and i'm calling the map and below i'm calling a listview and gridview.

The first time the map is displaying and i'm getting a listview but when i go to different fragment and come back to a same fragment i'm getting this error

```
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at com.dext.shoply.fragment.MapFragmentTest.onCreateView(MapFragmentTest.java:61)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:484)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16841)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 15:35:32.360: E/AndroidRuntime(22282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(M
```

**this is code i'm using for the map**

```
public class MapFragmentTest extends Fragment implements ShareItemClicked {

GoogleMap mapView;
private static View view;
public static ListView listView;
public static GridView gridview;
private GridAdapter gridAdapter;
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
 * available.
 */

private static GoogleMap mMap;
private static Double latitude, longitude;

public MapFragmentTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

// public static MapFragmentTest newInstance() {
// MapFragmentTest fragment = new MapFragmentTest();
// return fragment;
// }
// @Override
// public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
// super.onCreate(arg0);
// }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container, false);

    // Passing harcoded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as
    // per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
    latitude = 13.014471679122448;
    longitude = 80.20384224075353;
    // 13.014471679122448,80.20384224075353
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.location_map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
    // setUpMapIfNeeded(view, savedInstanceState); // For setting up the
    // MapFragment
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapgrid);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View",
            "Adapter implementation", "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android", "Android Example",
            "List View Source Code", "List View Array Adapter",
            "Android Example List View" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, values) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            /* YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR */
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            return view;
        }
    };

    // Assign adapter to ListView

    gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(getActivity(), Constant.hotDeals,
            this));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

/*****
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so
 * 
 * @param view2
 * @return
 *****/
/*
 * public static void setUpMapIfNeeded(View view2, Bundle
 * savedInstanceState) { // Do a null check to confirm that we have not
 * already instantiated the map. if (mMap == null) { // Try to obtain the
 * map from the SupportMapFragment. mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)
 * getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
 * .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap(); // Check if we were
 * successful in obtaining the map. if (mMap != null) setUpMap(); } }
 */

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
 * camera.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
 * is not null.
 */
private static void setUpMap() {
    // For showing a move to my loction button
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Home")
            .snippet("Home Address"));
    // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            latitude, longitude), 12.0f));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mMap != null)
        setUpMap();

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.location_map)).getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

@Override
public void shareItemClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gridAdapter.closeOther();
}

@Override
public void shareSponserItemClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map));

    if (fragment.isResumed()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

**my xml is**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ListView>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mapgrid"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**i'm calling the mapfragment class from another fragment 
using this method**

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position != 1)
            return TabChildFragment.newInstance(position, getActivity());
        else
            return new MapFragmentTest();
    }
```

can u guys help point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Is your main activity extends `FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: no that also a fragment

Comment: my main activity is a SlidingFragmentActivity in that i'm calling a fragment tab and in side that i'm calling this map fragment

Comment: @uer and what is your minsdk?

Comment: your main issue is your MapFragment is not properly destroyed>?

Comment: try as per my answer.

Comment: Did you check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554054/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-fragment

Answer (score 3):

try this `onDestroyView()` and remove `onDestroy()`

```
  @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        try{
          SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map));
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      super.onDestroyView();  
  }
```

Comment: i've try this but till now i'm facing the same issu plz help me

Comment: @user3705918 wait wait for a while

Answer (score 0):

if(yourfragment !==null) { getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourfragment).commit(); getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

} }

use this code for back click on fragment.