# android.view.InflateException Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to solve this problem from 5 days, but still I didn't get it solved.

**Main Java Code**

```
package com.beproject.ourway;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainHome extends FragmentActivity{
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_home);

    // Initialization

    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


    // Defining drawer items
    ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[6];

    drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Home");
    drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Places");
    drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Friends");
    drawerItem[3] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Settings");
    drawerItem[4] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Help");
    drawerItem[5] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "About");

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = 
            new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.home_drawer_item, drawerItem);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // selectItem(0);
}

public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

void selectItem(int position) {



    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    {
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    }
    case 1:
        fragment = new PlacesFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

public static class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}

public static class PlacesFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlacesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
}
```

**Main XML File**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.gaurav.googlemap.HomeMap" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
</fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_places.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Places"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at com.beproject.ourway.MainHome$HomeFragment.onCreateView(MainHome.java:105)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0017, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2164)
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
```

When I click on Home menu item from navigation drawer then it works fine. But when I click again on Home after then I get this exception

```
02-16 20:08:05.714: E/AndroidRuntime(5999): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

Is there any correction in java code? please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is after you initially load the Fragment, every time you go back to click the Home menu item, you are reloading the Fragment. You need to keep references to the fragments and mess with them, not instantiate new fragments.

Comment: How to do that? and where to change in my code?

Comment: Before you even commit to a more robust solution, simply have a `homeFragment` instance variable. Then, when you do `selectItem()`, in your case for 0, do something like `if (homeFragment == null) { homeFragment = new HomeFragment(); fragment = homeFragment; } else { fragment = homeFragment; }`

See what that does.

Comment: it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following variable to your Fragment class:

```
private static View view;
```

Then in that same fragment class try replacing the onCreateView Method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(view != null)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if(parent != null)
        {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places, container, false);
    }
    catch(InflateException e){
        // map is already there, just return view as it is
    }
    return view;
```

}